# How to rename NA-Column, in each dataframe in a list, in different positions

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list with a lot of dataframes.

The column names look like this:

```
[1] "TIMESTAMP"    "CLOSE"       
[3] "HIGH"         "LOW"         
[5] "OPEN"         NA            
[7] "daily_return"
```

One column, simply has no name.
And the order of the columns is in each element different.
This means that the "NA" column sometimes is in the beginning,
sometimes in the end, sometimes in the middle.

My goal is to give it a name,
and after that to reorder them,
so that each element of the list has the same
column names in the same order.

What I tried so far (makes just the NA column dissappear):

```
lapply(price_list_clean, FUN = function(X){X[c("TIMESTAMP",
                                                                     "OPEN",
                                                                     "HIGH",
                                                                     "LOW",
                                                                     "CLOSE",
                                                                     "daily_return",
                                                                     NA)]})
```

EDIT

My last take to identify the NA column and assign it a name:

```
for( i in 1:length(price_list_clean)){

  for(f in 1:ncol(price_list_clean[[i]])){

    if(is.na(colnames(price_list_clean[[i]])[f])){

      names(price_list_clean[[i]])[f] <- "RIC_Updated"

    }



  }

print(i)
}
```

Maybe anyone has an idea to do this more elegant?

Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
correct_order <- c("TIMESTAMP","OPEN","HIGH","LOW","CLOSE","daily_return","new_name")

price_list_clean  <- lapply(price_list_clean, function(x) {
  names(x)[match(TRUE, is.na(names(x)))] <- 'new_name'
  x[correct_order]
})
```

Comment: This is for the order or for the "NA" column?

Comment: Did you run this already? It doesn't give the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

We create a vector of custom order of column names, loop over the `list` of data.frames with `map`, use `rename_with` to change the column names that are 'NA' (assuming there is only one per data.frame), and `select` the columns in the order from the custom order vector of names

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
correct_order <- c("TIMESTAMP","OPEN","HIGH","LOW","CLOSE",
             "daily_return","new_name")
price_list_clean <- map(price_list_clean, ~ 
                     .x %>%
                       rename_with(~ 'new_name', matches("^NA$")) %>%
                       select(all_of(correct_order)))
```